# Need help on MAX CASE WHEN query to remove Null records

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Here's the SQL query with MAX CASE WHEN...

```
SELECT dbo.icalificaciones.idalumno, 
           dbo.ialumnosins.appaterno + ' ' + dbo.ialumnosins.apmaterno + ' ' + dbo.ialumnosins.nombre AS Alumnos,
    MAX(CASE WHEN idparcial = 1 THEN calfinal ELSE null END) AS U1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN idparcial = 2 THEN calfinal ELSE null END) AS U2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN idparcial = 3 THEN calfinal ELSE null END) AS U3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN idparcial = 4 THEN calfinal ELSE null END) AS U4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN idparcial = 5 THEN calfinal ELSE null END) AS U5,
    MAX(CASE WHEN idparcial = 6 THEN calfinal ELSE null END) AS U6,
    MAX(CASE WHEN idparcial = 7 THEN calfinal ELSE null END) AS U7,
    MAX(CASE WHEN idparcial = 8 THEN calfinal ELSE null END) AS U8
     FROM dbo.icalificaciones INNER JOIN dbo.ialumnosins ON  dbo.icalificaciones.idalumno = dbo.ialumnosins.IDalumno
```

here's the result.
how remove null values?
i dont need U2,U3,U4...U8.
thanks.

[image]

Comment: Don't include them in your query? Or are you saying you want to dynamically determine if an entire column in your result is null and exclude them?

Comment: yes, dynamically. some results has 8 columns. thanks

Comment: You will have to use dynamic sql in order to determine if you want to skip a certain column. It would be rather ugly. Why do you want to dynamically change the number of columns in a select statement like this? It seems to be fraught with challenges.

Comment: whats the case?, do you want to exclude the column if all of its rows are null or any of them?

Comment: hi,. Just the nulls.. some has U1 another has U1,U2.. to U8.

Comment: Create a procedure, set a boolean assigning a select statement to check whether all are nulls. If yes choose a select with only U1, else include others

Comment: is a good option,.. let me try

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to use the HAVING keyword.

Let's say you wanted to omit and records that return column U2 as NULL. You'd simply use:

```
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN idparcial = 2 THEN calfinal ELSE null END) is not null
```

at the end of your query.

Comment: But the column would still be in the result set because it is a column in the select list.

Comment: That's true, but since it seems to me a no brainer that if you don't want certain things in the select list, you can just remove them, i was trying to think of what else he could mean by what he said.

Comment: His title DID say he wanted to remove null records, not columns. :)

Comment: because, are records converted in columns by the MAX(CASE WHEN...)

Comment: True but in his example it clearly shows removing the columns, not the rows.

Comment: I wouldn't say "clearly". The very fact that the title is what it is leaves unclarity. Hence why this has yet to be resolved, based on results.